# PHP if statement with strlen (not working as expected)

Tags: php

```
<?php if(strlen($r['body'] <= '74')): ?>
<?php echo $r['body']; ?>
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo substr($r['body'], 0, 74) ."..."; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

when `$r['body']` == more than 74 chars everything works as expected but as soon as
`$r['body']` == less than 74 chars it still attaches "..."

I can work out what i have been doing wrong?

Comment: try taking out the quotes on the `strlen <=` statement

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are not closing right the strlen, also **74 is an integer should not be within quotes** try:

```
if(strlen($r['body']) <= 74):
```

Comment: I originally didn't have quotes but it wasn't working so well so quoted it and it worked... but as above, which now I see that It wouldn't have worked before because of not closing strlen properly. thanks.

Comment: Hey, i just noticed you posted that as a comment, you will find that posting at the same time happens a lot in Stack Overflow (and if you check the time on each posted i actually did first) sorry about it. BTW the quotes are in the integer not in the strlen..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php if(strlen($r['body'])  <= 74 ): ?>
```

`strlen()` return the length of string which you can test in `if`

Comment: Thats unbelievable, Iv spent the last 30-40mins trying to work out what the hell I did wrong, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have the parenthesis in the wrong place. try this:

```
<?php if(strlen($r['body']) <= '74'): ?>
```

Comment: the number should be out of quotes

Comment: php is weakly typed. it makes no difference.

Comment: it looks better outside quotes and is less confusing.